# How to put clear button beside p:calendar?

Tags: css, primefaces, calendar

I have a form which contains multiple elements, i have a primefaces calendar inside this form and i want to add a button beside the calendar input to allow user to set the date to null and clear the input field.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="date-depart">Date Départ 
  </label>
    <div class="row calendar-exibit col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <fieldset style="margin-bottom: -10px">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="col-md-11 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback" style="width: 85.667%; padding-left: 0px; border-radius: 3px;">
                        <p:calendar class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" locale="fr" id="ddepart" readonlyInput="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" value="#{travailleMB.datedepart}" placeholder="--- Date Depart ---" style="border-radius: 3px; font-size: 12px; padding-right: 9px; padding-top: 3px;">      
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{travailleMB.saveSelect}" process="@this"/>
                        </p:calendar>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h:button value="X" style="border-radius: 3px; font-size: 12px; margin-left:300px;"></h:button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

the following image is the result of this source code : [Form with input fields and the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWoPc.png)

I tried to put the button in different places of this form-group without success
Hope someone knows how to do it

Comment: Solution: use css (and you have so many of it in your code (via the classes) that is is impossible to tell what the solution is. Clean up the code and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this structure with the help of following HTML and CSS:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <p:calendar styleClass="form-control radius-none" value="#{xBean.dateValue}" />
    <span class="input-group-addon radius-none">
        <p:commandLink actionListener="#{xBean.clearDateValue}">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </p:commandLink>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-group {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.input-group .form-control,
.input-group-addon,
.input-group-addon-with-link,
.input-group-btn {
    display: table-cell !important;
}

.form-control {
    display: block!important;
    padding: 6px 12px!important;
    font-size: 14px!important;
    line-height: 1.42857143!important;
    color: #555!important;
    background-color: #fff!important;
    background-image: none!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

.radius-none {
    border-radius: 0!important;
}

.input-group-addon:last-child,
.input-group-addon-with-link:last-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-addon-with-link a,
.input-group-addon-with-link span {
    padding: 13px 15px;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-addon-with-link {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.input-group-addon,
.input-group-addon-with-link,
.input-group-btn {
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope this will help you out!

Comment: thank you @Parkash for your answer, it works fine but i have found another way to put the button beside the input and make it look like it's a part of it.